# Accessing iCloud photos uniquely on multiple devices using PHAsset

Tags: icloud, photosframework, phasset

Is there a way of accessing a specific `PHAsset` in an iCloud album uniquely on multiple devices?

I have written a simple app that lists thumbnails and `.localIdentifier`s from an iCloud shared album, and (naturally) it shows the same images on different devices, however, the localIdentifiers are different for the same images on different devices (not so unexpected as it is a "local" identifier).

However, what I actually want to do is associate a record in a cloud-shared CoreData database with an image in the cloud, rather than embed the image in the CoreData (it's a genealogy app, with potentially thousands of images) - for this I would need an identifier that is unique regardless of the device. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. In the early iOS 8 betas there was a cloud-identifier (which is exactly what you look for), but it was removed later on from the Photos API.

Comment: Surely it must be eventually reinstated?!?

Comment: If you want this feature, i suggest you submit a bug report / feature request at bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 7):

`PHAsset.cloudIdentifier` is available as private API.

```
let identifier = phAsset.value(forKey: "cloudIdentifier") as? String
```

Refer to iOS runtime header: https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/Photos.framework/PHAsset.h

Comment: Jonny your solution works perfectly. A real pity it is a private API. Have you tried to use it in some apps on the store that happened to get approved ? Thanks

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro currently I don't have apps that utilize this API. But for APIs like this, you can add some simple string obfuscation if you worry. E.g. `String(format: "%@%@%@", "clo", "udIdent", "ifier")`