# How to attach a short data to a photo in iOS/macOS cloud shared album?

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, photo, shared

I am building an app that shares photos between iOS/macOS users through the cloud shared album of the Photos application. I need each photo to be described by a few numbers carrying app-specific parameters.

I was researching through several ideas, none of which worked:

1. Writing numbers (or strings) into EXIF or IPTC meta-data fields

   - unfortunately, Apple cloud shared albums do not carry meta-data fields writable by a user
2. Inserting numbers into the photo filename e.g. `IMG_1234-i1-i2-...-iN.JPEG`

   - unfortunately, I can't find a way to change the filename of a photo in the Photos app.
3. Saving integers parallelly in an iCloud along with a photo identifier, so data can be retrieved on each device using the photo identifier

   - I assume that `PHObject.localIdentifier` is not persistent across the cloud shared albums read on different devices. I did not check this, but why otherwise the `identifier` would be called `local`?

**Is there any working way to bind a small amount of data to the photo in Cloud Shared Album of iOS/macOS Photos app**?

Comment: Possibly the wrong space to make this comment - but since it looks like you are adding photos to cloud shared albums - do you think you could take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079357/add-assets-to-an-icloud-shared-photo-album-programmatically) as the docs aren't clear about how to upload to iCloud shared albums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a description of a private API which I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42127181/2861254) I created the following extension to PHAsset:

```
extension PHAsset {
    var cloudIdentifier: String {
        return (self.value(forKey: "cloudIdentifier") as? String) ?? "?"
    }
}
```

The `cloudIdentifier` which you can get now from a `PHAsset` instance is persistent throughout the cloud on any devices sharing the same album. With persistent PHAsset identifier, one can implement solution #3 from the initial question.