# Add assets to an iCloud shared photo album programmatically

Tags: swift, icloud, photokit

Are there any limitations on using PhotoKit to add photos to Shared iCloud photo albums? While I can add new photos to AssetCollections that are regular albums, it does not work at all if the AssetCollection represents an iCloud sharing album. Do I also need to add a different type of PHAsset?

If I change the `fetchAssetCollections` call to use `.albumRegular` instead of `.albumCloudShared`, the code below works. Otherwise I get an error:

`The operation couldn't be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)`

```
let sharedAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .albumCloudShared, options: nil)

let target = sharedAlbums.firstObject

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: wantedimage)
    let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    let albumChangeRequestShared = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: target!)
    let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
    albumChangeRequestShared!.addAssets(enumeration)
}, completionHandler: { result, error in 
    print(result)
    print(error)
    print(error?.localizedDescription)
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can't add images to an iCloud shared album.

Prior to performing a change request you should call `canPerform(_:)` on the PHAssetCollection.

If you call `canPerform(_:)` on a `PHAssetCollectionSubtype` of `albumCloudShared` it will return false.

For example:

```
    print(collection.canPerform(.createContent)) //false
     
    print(collection.canPerform(.addContent)) //false
```

I had this same problem and submitted a feature request via the Feedback app.

Comment: Did you ever hear back on your feature request?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never heard anything back.